# How to test effects in ngrx?

Tags: redux, ngrx, effects, side-effects, ngrx-effects

I just want to get my getUser effect below.

I'm using angular5, typescript and ngrx.

I'm open to alternative examples to what I have below.

**This is my effect:**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import * as fromUser from '../actions/user-state.actions';
import { UserService } from '../services/user-state.service';
import { UserStateState } from '../models/user-state.interfaces';

@Injectable()
export class UserStateEffects {

  @Effect({ dispatch: true })
  getUser$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
    .ofType(fromUser.GET_USER)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.userService.getUser()),
      map((result: any) => new fromUser.UserSuccess(result)))
    .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => of(new fromUser.UserFailure(error)));

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}
}
```

**This is my spec for the effect test:**

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { cold, hot } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { empty } from 'rxjs/observable/empty';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import * as actions from '../actions/user-state.actions';
import { UserService } from '@tradingapplication/user-state/src/state/services/user-state.service';
import { UserStateEffects } from '@tradingapplication/user-state/src/state/effects/user-state.effects';
import { UserStateState } from '../models/user-state.interfaces';
import { UserStateConstants } from '../../user-state.constants';

export class TestActions extends Actions {
  constructor(){
    super(empty());
  }
  set stream(source: Observable<any>){
    this.source = source
  }
}

export function getActions() {
  return new TestActions();
}

fdescribe('UserStateEffects', function () {
  let actions$: TestActions;
  let service: UserService;
  let effects: UserStateEffects;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [
        UserService,
        UserStateConstants,
        UserStateEffects,
        { provide: Actions, useFactory: getActions },
      ],
    });

    actions$ = TestBed.get(Actions);
    service = TestBed.get(UserService);
    effects = TestBed.get(UserStateEffects);

    spyOn(service, 'getUser').and.returnValue(of(null));
  });

  it('should return user from GetUser', () => {
    const action = actions.GET_USER;
    const completion = new actions.UserSuccess({});

    actions$.stream = hot('-a', { a: action });
    const expected = cold('-b', { b: completion });

    expect(effects.getUser$).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You might want to check out the [NGRX example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/books/effects/book.effects.spec.ts) from the NGRX/Google team. It utilizes Jasmine-Marbles for testing streams, as used in NGRX Effects. This way you can test the streams for being closed or not after execution and how many elements passed through them before the expected value arrived. And all of that with just a few dashes (ticks).